# Can we store anything other than a valid date or null value in a date field?

Tags: oracle

I'm working on Oracle and Perl. I have three fields in a table (A, B, C), and I would like to form, for every row in the table, a string a_b_c using "join". C refers to a date. It can take null values. In that case , this "join" will return a warning "use of uninitialized values in join". I know that i have to select nvl(C,something) so that I get a_b_something when C is null. Can you suggest me what that "something" can be, if I want to distinguish between these rows and other rows.

In short, can I store anything other than a valid date or null value in a date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know that i have to select nvl(C,something) so that I get a_b_something when C is null

Selecting isn't *storing* the value in the column, and Oracle actually passes datetimes back to clients as strings, so it's entirely possible that you can just use `NVL(col, '')` without confusing DBI at all.

If that doesn't work out, you can always just build the whole thing up in SQL: just select

```
A || '_' || B || '_' || (CASE WHEN C IS NULL THEN '' ELSE TO_CHAR(C) END)
```

as one of your columns.

Comment: I want to store them as separate values. So,  NVL(col, '') should do it. Thank you !

Comment: FYI `(CASE WHEN C IS NULL THEN '' ELSE TO_CHAR(C) END)` yields *exactly* the same result as `TO_CHAR(C)`.

Answer (score 0):

As OMG Ponies said, you can't store a non-date in a DATE field in Oracle.

As hobbs intimated, you can use `NVL` to convert a null date into a string - for example, `NVL(TO_CHAR(C),'NULLDATE')` would return the string '`NULLDATE`' if the date is null.